# Setting max distance for Pull to refresh

Tags: codenameone

How can I set the max and min distance needed to apply push to refresh? Now sometimes the pull goes all the way to the bottom of the device which is not cool. I think there is a theme constant for the distance but could not find it now.

And how can I change the refresh text while pull to refresh is applied?

```
wrapContainerSingleTable.addPullToRefresh(new Runnable() {

 @Override
 public void run() {
     showEventsAndMeetingsComponents(wrapEventTabComponent, wrapMeetingTabComponent);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Can you provide a screeshot?

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit on the distance to my knowledge